# Rails 4, cocoon gem destroying created objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cocoon-gem

I have a big problem in my applications. It's little complicated so I will try explain it deeply. In my application I have model "Car":

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :prices,  dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :prices, allow_destroy: true

end
```

and "Price":

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
end
```

Im using wicked gem to have a wizard form. Im also use a cocoon gem to easily create some nested objects. 
My "Payment step html":

```
= simple_form_for [:partners, @car], url: wizard_path do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :prices do |price|
    = render 'price_fields', f: price
  #links
    = link_to_add_association 'add price', f, :prices
  = link_to t('cars.back'), edit_partners_car_path(@car)
  = f.submit t('cars.next'), class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

And price_fields:

```
.nested-fields
  %table.table.table-striped.table-bordered
    %thead
      %th
        = f.input :from_days
      %th  
        = f.input :to_days
      %th
        = f.input :netto_price
    = link_to_remove_association "X", f
```

And the problem is when I create some prices and go to the next step prices are saved into databse and everything is fine. But when I come back to this step and I click my:

```
= link_to_remove_association "X", f
```

it only hide this object but not delete it from database. It's big problem for me. I can't find issue. Please help if You can.

Comment: No one knows the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i change my "_price_fields" to:

```
.nested-fields
  %table.table.table-striped.table-bordered
    %thead
      %th
        = f.input :from_days
      %th  
        = f.input :to_days
      %th
        = f.input :netto_price
  = link_to_remove_association "X", f
```

my link_to_remove_association it was one level too deep...
Now works like charm